# Using Jax-ws WebTarget how to get remote IP Address for the service invoked?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am accessing a remote service using jax-rs client Webtarget, this remote service is using DNS Stub to load balance 6 nodes,

for eg: https://example.com/rest , this service will resolve to one of 6 nodes during execution

now how can i determine the ip address of the node that is being resolved for each call?

1st request may resolve to ip1

2nd request may resolve to ip2

I know all the ip's used by example.com, but i want to know the ip being used for a given service invocation.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you not have your service method call [InetAddress.getLocalHost()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost--)?

Comment: I dont have any control on the remote service,